# How to get detail from imagePreview.vshost process

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, c#-4.0

I've opened a image in window image viewer.Image can be any type of (jpg,png,gif). I want to get its detail

```
Process[] localByName = Process.GetProcessesByName("imagePreview.vshost");
 foreach (Process p in localByName)
    {
      if (!IsIconic(p.MainWindowHandle))
         {
             //detail about Image 
         }
      }
```

using above code I can only get the detail of process. Is it possible to get the path of image which is opened for example image resides in "C:\Users\65582\Pictures\abc.jpeg". Or how i can get the detail from image properties and then General tab:

[image: Image Properties]